# Asp.net App hosting from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, localhost, hosting

I am new to asp.net development. While running asp.net application visual studio first starts asp.net development environment and the application is hosted in localhost. Can we access the application (Web page) from other PC in the same network like we could do for the application hosted in IIS?

Is there any special configuration required in VS(we are using VS 2010) for that?

Thanks & Regards,
Arijit

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The best way is to create a new website in the IIS and to host your application there. In this way it could be accessed from the local network via the PC IP address. Just make sure you enable external connections on port 80 via your firewall/antivirus settings.